# receiving garbage values for pinvoke structure

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I am trying to send a structure from c# to c++ dll through PINVOKE

here is my code

C++ function

```
struct sampleStruct
{
int* intP;
char** charP;
};

TESTDLL_API int testStructCall(int *iPtr,char **cPtr,sampleStruct* st)
{ return 42;}
```

C# calling

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct sampleStruct
{
   public int[] intArr; 
   public string[] strArr;}

[DllImport("testDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,   CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    static private extern int testStructCall( int[] intArr, string[] strArr, ref sampleStruct st);


        string[] strArr = { "string 1", "string 2" };
        int[] intArr = { 10, 20, 30, 40 };

        sampleStruct struc = new sampleStruct();
        struc.intArr = intArr;
        struc.strArr = strArr;
        testStructCall( intArr,  strArr, ref struc);
```

here in C++ , I can receive first two Parameters correctly but the member of structure Shows garbage values. what am i missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in structs cannot be marshalled as `UnmanagedType.LPArray`, which is what you would need for these members to reach your unmanaged code.

As you probably know, the arrays are marshalled correctly when they appear as parameters to the function. If you must pass these arrays inside a struct, then you will need to declare the members as `IntPtr` in the C# struct declaration, and write the marshalling code manually. That's not very difficult for the integer array, it's just a case of pinning the array. For the string array then there is more work. You need an array of `IntPtr` which you then populate with calls to `Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi`.

It looks something like this:

```
var intHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(intArr, GCHandleType.Pinned);
struc.intArr = intHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();

var strPtrArr = new IntPtr[strArr.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < strPtrArr.Length; i++)
    strPtrArr[i] = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(strArr[i]);
var strHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(strPtrArr, GCHandleType.Pinned);
struc.strArr = strHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();

testStructCall(intArr, strArr, ref struc);

intHandle.Free();
strHandle.Free();
for (int i = 0; i < strPtrArr.Length; i++)
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(strPtrArr[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks , it works.  can i use IntPtr [] (Array of IntPtr ) in C# structure ? i am trying to send Array of Intptr.

Comment: I expect that will not be marshaled either just as int[] is not